# change color of words within an array

Tags: javascript

if i have an `javascript` `array` of words

```
var keywords = ["select","from","where","mars"];
```

and HTML element holding a text

```
<div id="mytext">Hello from planet mars</div>
```

How to use `javascript` to color in orange any word found in this element `mytext` of words list in the array `keywords` !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <div id="mytext">Hello from planet mars</div>
            <script>
                var keywords = ["select","from","where","mars"];
                mytext=document.getElementById("mytext");
                len=keywords.length;
                for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                    mytext.innerHTML=mytext.innerHTML.replaceAll(keywords[i],"<span style='color:orange;'>"+ keywords[i] +"</span>");
                }
                
            </script>
        <body>
```

You can use this code and replace the orange color with the color you want

```js
var keywords = ["select","from","where","mars"];
                mytext=document.getElementById("mytext");
                len=keywords.length;
                for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                    mytext.innerHTML=mytext.innerHTML.replaceAll(keywords[i],"<span style='color:orange;'>"+ keywords[i] +"</span>");
                }
```

```html
<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <div id="mytext">Hello from planet mars</div>
            
        <body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You should declare your variables. This will not work in strict mode.

Comment: This only changes the first instance of each word. Use `replaceAll` or a global regex to replace all instances.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
var keywords = ["select", "from", "where", "mars"];

let originalText = document.querySelector("#mytext").innerText

for (const word of keywords) {
  originalText = originalText.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"), `<span class="orange">${word}</span>`)
}

document.querySelector("#mytext").innerHTML = originalText
```

```css
.orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="mytext">Hello from planet mars</div>
```

we are iterating over the keywords and replacing the innerHTML with a new content where we would wrap mentions of the keyword with a markup that would give it a color.

Comment: Just suggest using the [Mark tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) instead of a span

Comment: This runs a new query and reassigns the innerHTML for every word in the array.

Comment: careful with iterating over `innerHTML` if there is actually html in the element it will replace element tag words as well. Better to use `textContent`

Comment: This also matches substrings (the **from** in **from**age) which the OP didn't clarify...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var keywords = ["select","from","where","mars"];
let div = document.getElementById('mytext')
let text_content = div.textContent.split(' ')

let html = text_content.map(e => {

    return keywords.includes(e) ? `<span class='orange'>${e}</span>` : e })

div.innerHTML = html.join(' ')
```

```css
.orange{
  color:orange;
  }
```

```html
<div id="mytext">Hello from planet mars</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var keywords = ["select","from","where","mars"];
const el = document.querySelector('#mytext');
keywords.map(kw => el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(new RegExp(kw, 'g'), '<span style="color: oragne">' + kw + '</span>'))
el.innerHTML = el.innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another regex option, but creating a single regex out of the array resulting in a single query/innerHTML assignment.

```js
const keywords = ["select","from","where","mars"];

const mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');

mytext.innerHTML = mytext.textContent.replace(
  new RegExp(`\\b${keywords.join('\\b|\\b')}\\b`, 'g'), 
  (match) => `<span class='orange'>${match}</span>`
);
```

```css
.orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="mytext">Hello from planet <span class="where">mars</span>, select from fromage mars.</div>
```

The resulting regex

```
/\bselect\b|\bfrom\b|\bwhere\b|\bmars\b/g
```